# Netbeans 6.8 Options dialog won't open

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Windows 7 and Netbeans 6.8.  When I try to open Tools > Options the icon spins for a moment or two and then.. nothing.  The Tools menu will expand, it's Options that is giving me the problem.  Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is StackOverflow material. Does it fit SuperUser? Anyone?

Comment: This isn't the really place to ask this sort of question. Or more specifically, I doubt you'll find an answer here. You could try SuperUser, but given the generic nature of the problem and the huge amount of possible solutions, you'd be better off contacting the guys behind Netbeans directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netbeans has a directory referred to as `${userdir}`.
On a windows platform this would be `%USERPROFILE%/.netbeans/6.8`.

- Shutdown NetBeans
- Remove `${userdir}/var/log/messages.log`
- Start NetBeans
- Try to open the Options panel
- Examine `${userdir}/var/log/messages.log` and see if an exception was logged.
- If there's an exception, add it to your question.

If there's no exception, close NetBeans and edit the file

```
${userdir}/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/options/api.properties
```

Look for the lines `OptionsX` and `OptionsY` and set their values to 100.
This ensures the options pane is on screen.
`OptionsWidth` and `OptionsHeight` should be roughly `600` and `800` respectively.

Comment: This information fixed this same problem in Netbeans 7 as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem where the preferences window wouldn't open on MacOSX. Do you know where I can find the same settings?

Comment: Depending on the version of NetBeans the ${userdir} is either `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/` or `/Users/<username>/.netbeans`

Comment: Check `Menu >> Help >> About` for you `{userdir}` location (it varies from NB versions).    
In NB 7.2 to 8.0 it's located at  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\options\api.properties`